# In Xcode 6 how to create uiviewcontroller containing two side by side table views

Tags: uitableview, swift, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard

I am making a Swift app that will use two side-by-side table views to represent a bid and an ask queue. I'm new to Storyboards so I'm not sure if what I'm doing is possible, or if it's just a quirk of the Xcode Beta, but I'm trying to create this view layout using a Storyboard. The simplest method of doing this seems to be to drag and drop a UIViewController onto the canvas, and then drag and drop two UITableViews into that UIViewController. So far the IB won't let me drag and drop a UITableView into the controller, nor into a UITableViewController. How can I accomplish this?